# Handling one to many relationship in MVC model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am new to MVC and I want to develop a functionality where user can add multiple languages in register forms.

In this I need to put one dropdown which contains all languages and a Add button beside it. if user clicks on add selected language is bind to a control(label or li) above dropdown with remove button beside it.

User can add as many languages he/she knows and also fills up other information and when finally submit the form we should get all values in model on server side and it save into database.

In this I need to use strongly typed view with registration model. This model contains properties like first name of `string` type, last name of `string` type, language of type `List<string>`.

Comment: What is your property for the languages - `List<what>`? (and adding it to a `<label>` or `<li>` will not bind to your model - you need a form control (e.g. `<input>`). But why not just use a `<select multiple>` or  checkbox list?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for reply. It is of List<string> typed, and we may have multiple language more than 10 so we cannot use checkbox as it will messy. Clients needs it like, with add and remove button, so we need to keep it like that way. Please check this image https://www.screencast.com/t/CeMwb4FDvld4 for more details.

Comment: Well your client does not understand good UI design, but if your property is `List<string> Languages`, the you just need to create inputs with `<input name="languages" .. />` and their values will bind to your property.